# errors in the tutorial (Interpreting Machine Learning Models with the iml Package)

Tags: r, iml

I am getting the following error when trying to execute the following code in section entitled "Replication requirements" (https://uc-r.github.io/iml-pkg):

```
#classification data
df <- rsample::attrition %>%
mutate_if(is.ordered, factor, ordered = FALSE) %>%
mutate(Attrition = recode(Attrition, "Yes" = "1", "No" = "0") %>% factor(levels = c("1", "0")))

> Error: 'attrition' is not an exported object from 'namespace:rsample'
```

The problem was solved using the following code:

```
#data
library(modeldata)
data("attrition", package = "modeldata")
#classification data
df <- attrition %>%
mutate_if(is.ordered, factor, ordered = FALSE) %>%
mutate(Attrition = recode(Attrition, "Yes" = "1", "No" = "0") %>% factor(levels = c("1", "0")))
```

Unfortunately, I got another error after trying to execute the following code (section entitled "Global interpretation/Feature importance" (https://uc-r.github.io/iml-pkg):

```
#compute feature importance with specified loss metric
imp.glm <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.glm, loss = "mse")
imp.rf <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.rf, loss = "mse")
imp.gbm <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.gbm, loss = "mse")

> Error in [.data.frame(prediction, , self$class, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

> Error in [.data.frame(prediction, , self$class, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected

> Error in [.data.frame(prediction, , self$class, drop = FALSE) : undefined columns selected
```

I use R 4.2.0/ Win10

Comment: it is possible that the link may have some typos/errors based on the first error (or possibly it worked in an earlier version of the package)

Comment: Just to clarify earlier comment.  If you check the `?attrition`, from `rsample`, there is a line which states `These data are now in the modeldata package`.  So, it is possible that the info in the link would be old enough to result in errors

Comment: Compared to the example at https://rdrr.io/cran/iml/man/FeatureImp.html the code seems to be correct

Comment: it is possible that minor behavior changes in the functions caused this issue.  As mentioned in the comment above, this link could be old

Comment: Yes this is old, there is package & session info at the end of the tutorial page

Comment: The "rsample" package allows to pull "attrition" data from the "modeldata" package,, see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rsample/vignettes/Working_with_rsets.html

Comment: Did anybody find solution for this error? rror in `[.data.frame`(prediction, , self$class, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

Answer (score 3):

The parameters shown in the tutorial need to be altered slightly; instead of `class = "classification"`, change it to `class = 2` (per [the docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/iml/versions/0.11.0/topics/Predictor)) and the example works as expected:

```r
library(rsample)   # data splitting
library(ggplot2)   # allows extension of visualizations
library(dplyr)     # basic data transformation
library(h2o)       # machine learning modeling
#install.packages("iml")
library(iml)       # ML interprtation
#install.packages("modeldata")
library(modeldata)
library(R6)

h2o.no_progress()
h2o.init()
#>  Connection successful!
#> 
#> R is connected to the H2O cluster: 
#>     H2O cluster uptime:         9 minutes 18 seconds 
#>     H2O cluster timezone:       Australia/Melbourne 
#>     H2O data parsing timezone:  UTC 
#>     H2O cluster version:        3.36.0.1 
#>     H2O cluster version age:    6 months and 28 days !!! 
#>     H2O cluster name:           H2O_started_from_R_jared_mpb432 
#>     H2O cluster total nodes:    1 
#>     H2O cluster total memory:   1.58 GB 
#>     H2O cluster total cores:    4 
#>     H2O cluster allowed cores:  4 
#>     H2O cluster healthy:        TRUE 
#>     H2O Connection ip:          localhost 
#>     H2O Connection port:        54321 
#>     H2O Connection proxy:       NA 
#>     H2O Internal Security:      FALSE 
#>     H2O API Extensions:         Amazon S3, XGBoost, Algos, Infogram, AutoML, Core V3, TargetEncoder, Core V4 
#>     R Version:                  R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)

df <- modeldata::attrition %>% 
  mutate_if(is.ordered, factor, ordered = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(Attrition = recode(Attrition, "Yes" = "1", "No" = "0") %>%
           factor(levels = c("1", "0")))

# convert to h2o object
df.h2o <- as.h2o(df)

# create train, validation, and test splits
set.seed(123)
splits <- h2o.splitFrame(df.h2o, ratios = c(.7, .15), destination_frames = c("train","valid","test"))
names(splits) <- c("train","valid","test")

# variable names for resonse & features
y <- "Attrition"
x <- setdiff(names(df), y) 

# elastic net model 
glm <- h2o.glm(
  x = x, 
  y = y, 
  training_frame = splits$train,
  validation_frame = splits$valid,
  family = "binomial",
  seed = 123
)

# random forest model
rf <- h2o.randomForest(
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  training_frame = splits$train,
  validation_frame = splits$valid,
  ntrees = 1000,
  stopping_metric = "AUC",    
  stopping_rounds = 10,         
  stopping_tolerance = 0.005,
  seed = 123
)
#> Warning in .h2o.processResponseWarnings(res): early stopping is enabled but neither score_tree_interval or score_each_iteration are defined. Early stopping will not be reproducible!.

# gradient boosting machine model
gbm <-  h2o.gbm(
  x = x, 
  y = y,
  training_frame = splits$train,
  validation_frame = splits$valid,
  ntrees = 1000,
  stopping_metric = "AUC",    
  stopping_rounds = 10,         
  stopping_tolerance = 0.005,
  seed = 123
)
#> Warning in .h2o.processResponseWarnings(res): early stopping is enabled but neither score_tree_interval or score_each_iteration are defined. Early stopping will not be reproducible!.

# model performance
h2o.auc(glm, valid = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.7870935
## [1] 0.7870935
h2o.auc(rf, valid = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.7681021
## [1] 0.7681021
h2o.auc(gbm, valid = TRUE)
#> [1] 0.7468242
## [1] 0.7468242

features <- as.data.frame(splits$valid) %>% select(-Attrition)

# 2. Create a vector with the actual responses
response <- as.vector(as.numeric(splits$valid$Attrition))

# 3. Create custom predict function that returns the predicted values as a
#    vector (probability of purchasing in our example)
pred <- function(model, newdata)  {
  results <- as.data.frame(h2o.predict(model, as.h2o(newdata)))
  return(results[[3L]])
}

# example of prediction output
pred(glm, features) %>% head()
#> [1] 0.12243347 0.12887908 0.09674399 0.26008143 0.00672000 0.13741387

predictor.glm <- Predictor$new(
  model = glm, 
  data = features, 
  y = response, 
  predict.fun = pred,
  class = "classification"
)
predictor.glm$predict(features[1:10,])
#> Error in `[.data.frame`(prediction, , self$class, drop = FALSE): undefined columns selected
# class = "classification" doesn't make sense; from the docs:
### The class column to be returned in case of multiclass output.
### You can either use numbers, e.g. class=2 would take the 2nd column
### from the predictions, or the column name of the predicted class,
### e.g. class="dog".
# so, in this case, 'class = 2' should work as expected

predictor.glm <- Predictor$new(
  model = glm, 
  data = features,
  y = response,
  predict.function = pred,
  class = 2
)
predictor.glm$predict(features[1:10,])
#>            p1
#> 1  0.12243347
#> 2  0.12887908
#> 3  0.09674399
#> 4  0.26008143
#> 5  0.00672000
#> 6  0.13741387
#> 7  0.47917917
#> 8  0.11775822
#> 9  0.11316964
#> 10 0.22963757

predictor.rf <- Predictor$new(
  model = rf, 
  data = features, 
  y = response, 
  predict.fun = pred,
  class = 2
)

predictor.gbm <- Predictor$new(
  model = gbm, 
  data = features, 
  y = response, 
  predict.fun = pred,
  class = 2
)

imp.glm <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.glm, loss = "mse")
imp.rf <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.rf, loss = "mse")
imp.gbm <- FeatureImp$new(predictor.gbm, loss = "mse")

p1 <- plot(imp.glm) + ggtitle("GLM")
p2 <- plot(imp.rf) + ggtitle("RF")
p3 <- plot(imp.gbm) + ggtitle("GBM")

#gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, nrow = 1)
p1
```

[image]

```r
p2
```

[image]

```r
p3
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: The proposed solution works fine and the code is executing, but every feature seems to be important - the results differ from those presented in the tutorial.

Comment: It was difficult to see the results in the previous version of the code because they were all 'squashed together'; I've updated the code to print each plot individually and changed `class = 1` to `class = 2` to get the same orientation as in the tutorial @tomek

Comment: I found a solution to this question presented earlier. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69930234/overcoming-compatibility-issues-with-using-iml-from-h2o-models

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate the variable importance (using the `h2o` package), for your `glm` model (just choosing one for the example) as follows:

`h2o::h2o.varimp(glm)`

Example output:

[image: Example output]

Does this achieve what you wanted?

Note: I'm assuming you've run all the code up to that point in the link you provided, i.e. that you have created the `glm` model object using the code provided in the link.

Comment: I used the randomForest, and iml package to successfully depict feature interactions for the wine dataset (not using this tutorial). But here, the question is why I cannot successfully execute the next pieces of code using the iml package (the aim of this tutorial is to calculate and visualize feature interactions by H-statistics). The code  (interact.glm <- Interaction$new(predictor.glm) %>% plot() + ggtitle("GLM")
) from the section "Measuring interactions" of this tutorial generate again this error.

Comment: Interactions in the H20 are documented: https://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/interactions.html